# Running on eclipse shows error

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I did git clone a repository and try working on files in it but when I try to run, "Error: Could not find or load main class " shows up every time.

So far on Eclipse, I created a workspase and cloned a repository there which is supposed to have two two folders. In one folder, there are starter codes that I need to work on for this assignment but when I cannot run it...

Comment: There is no such thing as a main class in JavaScript. Did you mean Java?

Comment: What sort of project is this? Eclipse plugins also don't have a main class.